# Git merge - Treat any auto file change as a conflict (do not stage), like a --squash

Tags: git, merge

I am merging a large series of unwrapped tags from master into a topic branch and am using:

```
git --no-commit --no-ff tagName^0
```

And it works as it *should*. Besides the actual hard file conflicts created, I need to review and hand edit a large number of files that have incorrect auto-merges due to needing a human to determine the proper strategy (like you do during a *git add -p filename*).

So, first, is there a way to prevent auto-staging of any (all) files in a merge?

And is there a way to do a "merge --squash", manually edit the files (git add -p) and then actually transform that into a MERGE_HEAD on the next commit so that commit has two parents and becomes the next merge base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to prevent auto-staging of any (all) files in a merge?

Yes.  Use `git merge --no-ff --strategy=ours` to leave a no-op merge uncommitted, that's baseline for doing a hand-roll merge, then use
`git read-tree`'s merge setup to do all the low-level prep except conflict resolution, selecting options for which situations you want it to handle for you.

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit -s ours topic
git read-tree -um $(git merge-base @ topic) @ topic
```

<sup><sup>[git merge docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) . . . [git read-tree docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree)</sup></sup>

This does all the only-one-branch-changes stuff but leaves anything with a hint of conflict for you to resolve.

You can get the three different versions of each file that needs merging with

```
git ls-files -u \
| git checkout-index --stage=all --stdin

# do the manual resolutions you don't want any automerge for here
```

<sup><sup>[git ls-files docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) . . . [git checkout-index docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)</sup></sup>

When you're done with all your manual resolutions git shouldn't touch at all you can clean up with git's auto-resolver for the rest with `git merge-index -ao git-merge-one-file`,

```
git merge-index -ao git-merge-one-file

# resolve any conflicts automerge can't figure for you

git add all-the-correctly-merged-files-you-havent-already-added
git commit
```

<sup><sup>[git merge-index docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-index)</sup></sup>

Comment: Ah, do a read-tree after a merge -s ours... nice!... ok, off to give this a shot to see if it all works. FYI: I'm merging from a master to a topic so some of the topics you listed become an unwrapped tag from the master.

Comment: Having issues with the merge-base not being moved up... still working through why this is occuring using these steps.