# Display git diff in merge resolution format

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-patch

Is there a way to format a git diff (e.g. `git diff HEAD^` or `git diff origin/foo origin/bar`) in the format used by merge resolution?

For example, I have a patch which (in part) looks like

```
   yield (
     api.test('check the foos') +  #
-    api.properties(foos=[]) +  #
     api.frobozz(bar) +  #
     ...
   )
```

And I would like to see this section as

```
yield (
   api.test('check the foos') +  #
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< origin
   api.properties(foos=[]) +  #
=============================
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> HEAD
   api.frobozz(bar) +  #
   ...
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644096/git-merge-treat-any-auto-file-change-as-a-conflict-do-not-stage-like-a-sq may be useful here. I can't see how to turn it into an answer to my question, but several answers seem like relevant pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no: `git diff` only compares *two* commits, and `git merge` runs two *different* `git diff` operations, and then combines the results of those two diffs, which is why `git merge` has the necessary information.

To get the necessary information, you need a *third* commit: a common starting point for the two different diffs that you will generate and then combine.  What is the common starting point for these two commits?  If you can find or manufacture one, *then* you can get what you'd like.

(If you just want to manufacture a *fake* third commit by editing the output of `git diff`, you can write a program to do that, of course.  But you must write the program: Git does not come with any such thing.)

Comment: There is only one commit. Not two. If there were two, I could get this with a rebase. What part of my example was not clear?

Comment: Well, OK, in your case there's one commit and one other file-tree, either in the index, or in your work-tree. The point is, to get the kind of diff you want, you need *three* file trees (three commits, or two commits and the index, etc). In any case the short answer remains no: Git won't do that for you.

Comment: How would someone achieve this with 3 trees?

Comment: @zaabson: what output would you like when tree A has file F1 with contents C1, tree B has file F1 with contents C2, and tree C has file F2 (renamed from F1) with contents C1? What sort of diff should this show when a file exists in all three trees but has differing contents in each? (There are potential answers to these questions: Git produces *combined diffs* for some situations. However, combined diffs have issues, so there's no *right* answer.)

Comment: @torek I imagine one tree being a common ancestor of the two. And the diff to show on top of the base from common ancestor, where the two newer trees differ.

Comment: @zaabson That sounds a lot like the combined diff you get with `-c` or `--cc` applied to a merge commit (see [this section of the diff docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format)). But there's no mechanism in the `git diff` family to invoke it on some trees, and it's the reverse of what you've suggested: instead of a single ancestor with two or more descendants, it's a single descendant (the merge commit) with two or more ancestors.